# How to send a captioned image via share link in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, does anyone know how to code a `ShareLink` that will allow the user to choose Messages as a destination for an image and some text (effectively, a caption)?

Here I've implemented a simple version that uses two `ShareLink`s to send the information, but separately, requiring far too many taps to achieve the desired result:

```swift
struct CaptionedImageShare: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let image = Image(systemName: "globe")
            ShareLink(item: image, preview: SharePreview("The World", image: image))
            ShareLink(item: "Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

(I don't know why the globe image is so faint when being shared, but I don't need that to be fixed for this educational example).